# How MySQL's LIMIT will change dynamically based on inserted rows

Tags: mysql, autohotkey

My table has three fields, namely `ID (auto-increment)` as `primary key`, `lastmodified (ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` and `MainframeID`.
My table will have a data inserted in a random basis.
I need to issue this query:

```
SELECT MainframeID 
FROM testing 
ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 2
```

To retrieve data recently inserted with a limit of two rows.
I have a problem when just using `LIMIT 2`.
Is there a possibility to dynamically change the `LIMIT` based on the inserted rows/data?

Additional Info: I am using Autohotkey to query to MySQL and send the data over to IBM PCOMM.

Comment: You say you want to dynamically change the limit, but what determines your desired limit?

Comment: Is it duplicates that you want to ignore?

Comment: The desired limit will be based on the inserted row.
For example, there were three inserted rows, the limit will dynamically changed to LIMIT 3.

I will incorporate the SQL statement into Autohotkey, my pseudocode shown below:

if records added = 1
LIMIT should be 1

else if records added = 2
LIMIT should be 2

Kickstart, sort of, I don't want to fetch and send data that has already been included from the first select query.

Comment: So, is it the case that you want to return all rows since your previous query?

Comment: Yes, I want to return all row since my previous query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are also using AutoHotkey to run the query that inserts the new records, you can save the number of records inserted in a variable in your AHK script.

If this won't work for you, you can try checking the most recently inserted rows, and if the time modified is less than a second apart, than assume that it's part of the most recent insert.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please consider accepting it.  Thanks!!